# AngularJs-e2e Test with protractor: how to connect to server via websocket

Tags: angularjs, websocket, protractor, cucumber

My application is based on osgi-model running on felix server. The GUI is in Angular.
I am developing the GUI test in parallel to the backend developper. There are not much GUI-screens implemented yet, so it is early to use protractor to test the GUI-functionality.

However I would like to "pretend beying the gui" and send and receive some events via Felix. This way I can test some primary known backend functionalities which are fired by frontend.

But I don't know how to send events to felix-server! I tought to open a websocket connection to felix-server, then sending events to it. Here is my code:

```
//websocket2Felix.js

var websocket =null;

module.exports = {
    openConnection: function() {
        try{
           websocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/myproj");
           websocket.onopen = function(evt) { onOpen(evt) };
           websocket.onclose = function(evt) { onClose(evt) };
           websocket.onmessage = function(evt) { onMessage(evt) };
           websocket.onerror = function(evt) { onError(evt) };
        }
        catch(err){
            browser.logger.info( err.message + "/n");
        }
      },

      doSend: function(message) {
          browser.logger.info("SENT: " + message);
           websocket.send(message);
      }
};   

function onOpen(evt) {
  }
function onClose(evt) {
  }
function onMessage(evt) {
  }
function onError(evt) {
  }
```

I use this code in my test-case definition, which I wrote using cucumber-syntax:

```
//home_steps.js
var websocketOnFelix = require ('./websocket2Felix.js');

var homeSteps = function() {
    this.Given(/^I am on the home$/, function () {
      browser.get("path/to/home");
     });

   this.When(/^I click on help button$/, function(){
      //open websocket to felix to send gui-events to it
       browser.pause();
       websocketOnFelix.openConnection();
       browser.pause();
       /////// here to send the click event to felix//////
    });

  this.Then(/^The help screen should be displayed$/, function(){        
      el= element(by.css('#help-screen'));
      expect( el.isPresent() ).to.be.ok;
    });

});
```

This is my cucmber-configuration:

```
//cucumConfig.js

'use strict';

exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
    getPageTimeout: 60000,
    allScriptsTimeout: 500000,
    framework: 'custom',        
    frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
    output:'./output.json',                

    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome'
      },

    specs: [
        '*.feature'
      ],

    cucumberOpts: {
        require: '*_steps.js',
        tags: false,
        format: 'pretty',
        profile: false

      },          

};
```

When I call

```
protractor cucumbConfig.js
```

after this line "websocketOnFelix.openConnection();" I get a quite in the  console never reaching the next line in the test-case;

After adding a try-catch-block, the error arised from the line

```
websocket = new WebSocket(...);
```

is: "WebSocket is not defined".

Any idea, what I am doing wrong? 
Thank you much.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to install the WebSocket package ([npm install here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket)) then call ('require') the necessary file in the top of websocket2Felix.js
 as directed in the link.

Comment: I had installed WebSocket package before I used it. I guess the problem is something of kind synchronious/asynchronious communication.